# how to stop asyncktask from Navigation Drawer or is it possible

Tags: android, android-asynctask, navigation-drawer

I'm using many Async Task.I have navigation drawer and there one button is there. on click this button I'm going to next activity .so how to stop asynck task from Navigation Drawer . asyncktask .cancel(true), how to use in navigation drawer because asyncktask in main activity.or how to get object of asynck task from mainactivity to Navigation Drawer.i m in same activity and on activity i m calling navigation drawer.help me i m struging in many days. it is  possible or not?

Comment: i want to stop all asyncktask of mainactivity from naviationdrawer before going to next Activity

Comment: I would say, call asyncTask.cancel(true) from the onClick handler of your navigation drawer's button. Or, if it's a menu from onMenuItemSelected

Comment: but but Asyncktast i m  calling in Mainactivity

Comment: keep your asyncTask as a field in your activity then, this way you can access it within your activity

Comment: you should do in onStop() method

Comment: i want to do same but how to get asyncktast object referent should i have to send trought naviation drawer constructor

Comment: suppose i ahe asyncktask1 in main menu how  call means asyncktask1.cance(true)will say. cannot find synboll

Answer (score 1):

In your situation `LocalBraodcastManager` will be handy

Use it like this

At MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Cancel all your asyncTask here
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And from the Navigation Drawer

```
Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Hope you can solve issue with this.

Comment: tnx i will try i will upvote plz upvode my question also

Comment: i have 1 question i m in naviation drawer